# Reduction of Order Strategy using $y' = p$ and $y'' = p\frac{dp}{dy}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been given the following form to solve a differential equation:

> If a differential equation does not contain x explicitly for instance: $$F(y,y', y'')=0$$Then putting $y' = p$ and $y'' = p\frac{dp}{dy}$ we get an equation of an order one unit lower: $$F(y,p,p\frac{dp}{dy})=0$$

I am not sure I totally understand the definition. Please correct me if I am wrong:

1. The first part tells me that $y$ may not be a function of only $x$?
2. How do we get $y'' = p\frac{dp}{dy}$ from  $y' = p$? I don't see this easily.

Thanks.

Comment: For the second bullet point, remember we're taking a derivative with respect to our independent variable (let's say $x$) so $y'' = \frac{dp}{dx} = \frac{dp}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx} = p\frac{dp}{dy}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the function $y$ you eventually find will be a function of only x.  There is no other independent variable in the equation.

Second,

$ y^{\prime \prime} = \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}p=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d}{dy}p=p\frac{d}{dy}p$